# Firefox/Gecko loading css in another domain??what does it mean?

Tags: css, firefox, browser, requirejs, gecko

Following is an extract from Requirejs documentation :

> *Ideally RequireJS could load CSS files as dependencies. However, there are issues knowing when a CSS file has been loaded, particularly in **Gecko/Firefox** when the file is loaded from another domain. Some history can be found in this Dojo ticket.*

Can anyone please explain what is happening in Gecko/Firefox??? it says they load files from another domain??what does it mean???

please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are just referring to when sites use cdns to host static content.  Using a different usually cookie less domain to host their css, images and js files.  Not that Gecko/Firefox is doing something to all css, images and js files.  I'm not sure why Gecko is different from other browsers during these conditions they describe however.